# I am having issues adding multiple url parameters to the same line in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters, query-string

Currently my .htaccess looks like this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^age
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^gender
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^languages
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sites
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sortOrder
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^status
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tags
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404]
```

At the moment this works well, if I visit a URL with one of the parameters it will give me a 404 page, I want to know if there is a better way to write this.

**Is it possible to combine all these into one line?**

I have tried writing it like this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^age
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^gender
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^languages
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sites
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sortOrder
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^status
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tags
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404]
```

But that didn't work as it would only work for the top query and not the rest of them

Comment: "if I visit a URL with one of the parameters it will give me a 404 page" - Although that's not strictly what those directives do. You are only targeting the "homepage" (ie. empty URL-path) and only when one of those strings (or nothing at all) exists at the start of the query string. It doesn't trigger a 404 if any of those "strings" occur later in the query string (eg. `/?foo&age=1`) and it doesn't just block whole parameter names. eg. `/?agefoo=1` would also be blocked. Is that the intention?

Comment: @MrWhite yes but is there a better way to write it so it looks more like 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param1 param2 param3 param4 param5 param6
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried writing it like this
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^age
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^gender
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^languages
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sites
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sortOrder
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^status
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tags
> RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404]
> ```

`RewriteCond` directives (*conditions*) are implicitly AND'd, so the above will never be successful (ie. no 404 occurs) since the query string can not match all those strings at the same time.

You need to use the `OR` flag on all but the last *condition*. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^& [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^age [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^gender [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^languages [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sites [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sortOrder [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^status [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tags
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404]
```

However, this can be further reduced using regex *alternation*. For example, the above is the same as the following using just one *condition*:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(&|age|gender|languages|sites|sortOrder|status|tags)
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404]
```